# Reference on Probability theory on functional spaces (in special Hilbert spaces)

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Currently, I am working on some sort of stochastic optimization problems defined over function spaces.

I am familiar with standard probability theory (R. **Durrett**, ''Probability: Theory and Examples"). However, the standard discussions are restricted to random objects in Euclidean spaces (random vectors and variables). I like to know whether there are some proper references on extensions of these notions and theorems (*WLLN, SLLN, CLT, Conditional Expectation,*...) to the case where the objects of interest belong to a function space.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can start with "Analysis and Probability on Infinite-Dimensional Spaces" by Nathaniel Eldredge, and the references therein:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03591

For a comprehensive treatment of probability in Banach spaces, see
Ledoux and Talagrand: "Probability in Banach Spaces", Springer 2011.